# I want to use PI in my code of iphone SDK 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How can i use PI in the objective-C ?? How to write coding if i want to do

(36.12*pi)/180 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the constant M_PI. Your code would look like this:

```
(36.12 * M_PI)/180;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the constant `M_PI`